# How do I switch a dictsort in Django with a click of a button?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I'm trying to make a button that whenever someone clicks on it it'll change my dictsort to sort by a different attribute instead. Here's my code. I don't have any errors but the button isn't doing anything. I want the dictsort to switch to sorting by date if someone clicks on the button instead of sorting by authors which is the default. Thanks in advance.

```
<button type="submit" onClick="{change text.for-loop|dictsort:'date'}"></button>
<ol  class="text">
    {% for paragraph in paragraphs|dictsort:"authors" %}
        <div>{{paragraph.text}}</div>
    {% endfor %}
</ol>
```

Comment: You don't. Django renders templates at server side, so the `onclick` will never trigger any template logic, since the template is rendered *before* it is handed over to the browser.

Comment: You will need to look for some JavaScript to do the trick.

Comment: Oh okay thank you.